# Android UI Design: Supporting Multiple Screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I have read this tutorial [SUPPORTING MULTIPLE SCREENS](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) several times and many stackoverflow questions regarding `Design Android UIs to fit well with all android screen sizes`.

But still struggling with providing the best and the same user experience for all screen sizes equally.

When I am designing the Interfaces always keeping the following diagram in mind.[image]

For the moment in my app it uses following folder structure under the res folder.

[image]

Also I have used **dp** and **sp** units in the xml layout files when defining the sizes.

**Small screen sizes**

When it comes to small screen sizes it perfectly refer to the UIs defined under `layout-small` and display without any issue.

**Normal screen sizes**

When I design layouts for normal screen sizes`(layout folder)`, I used `3.5 inches` android device and `3.7 inches` emulator to test how UI looks like in normal screen size.

So my layouts look excellent in this size but Samsung Gallaxy S3 (`4.8 inches`) and S4 (`5.0 inches`) having slightly bigger screens and they still refer to the normal screen sized layouts. Therefore in Those bigger screens have a considerable space left from the bottom not using and UI doesn't look nice.

Also In the manifest file, I have defined the following,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

I have no issue with the image density(`drawable-hdpi/drawable-xhdpi/drawable-mdpi/drawable-ldpi`)

**(1).** Wonder what I am missing or doing wrong to result like this specially in Bigger screens (4.8 inches) to refer normal layouts.

**(2).** Also If someone can explain best practices and the standard way of defining folder structure under the `Res` folder to fit well with all the screen sizes in android, would be grateful as this is so confusing. Thanks.

Comment: You can specify layout folders for specific resolutions and screen sizes. That's the new way of doing this.

Comment: Do you know what the width/height `dp` of 4.8in and 5in screens are?

Answer (score 18):

Instead of using the dp size unit you can use [the sdp size unit](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) that is relative to the screen size.

Using [the sdp size unit](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) you will have the same user experience on all screen sizes with only one layout xml.

Use it carefully! for example, in most cases you still need to design a different layout for tablets.

For text view sizes please refer to [the ssp size unit](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) (based on the sp size unit)

Comment: Thanks a lot life saver :)

Comment: Ok this is something new I heard

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following resource folders to create layouts for devices with larger screens :

7 inch tablets
`res\layout-sw600dp`

10 inch tablets
`res\layout-sw720dp`

Comment: Hi Plato, Thanks for the Answer but this way had intriduced to work in Android 3.2 and higher versions as I know. In my case minimum supporting version is Android 1.6(android:minSdkVersion="4"). Also my issue is regarding the "normal" sized screens. I wonder how to design a set of layouts to work well with Galaxy S3/S4 (4.8inches range devices) at the same time work well in 3.7 inches(Normal sized) devices...

Comment: Then the only thing that comes to mind is to make your layouts to adjust automatically to the screen size by using MATCH_PARENT or the weight functionality of different layouts.

Comment: Yes Plato, I have used the layouts to adjust automatically as you have explaibed here. So it gets the full Horizontal space(width) and ok in every case...... The problem is no way to adjust layout items to use the full verticle space in screen(Height). When I adjust the Normal sized UIs to work well for the 3.5-3.7 inches size it leaves considerable amount of space from bottom when it comes to 4.8-5.0 inches level screens as they also refer to the same Normal sized UIs.

Comment: You can use weight within a Vertical LinearLayout for example to make a view to fill some space vertically. Or you mean that your layout is designed like this so it can be scaled vertically?

Answer (score 1):

If it is very important to specify to that extreme, there is a handy tool for folder naming, and that is chaining. Ex. `layout-w480dp-normal` and that would be screen sizes at least `480dp` in width, and fall under the `normal` category. Note: I didn't get the need to develop for such detailed requirements, but according to the linked source, it should work just fine.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

[Make sure to follow these rules](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules)

Answer (score 1):

For Multiple screen support:

1. **Mobile :** Create different values folder which is mention below:

```
values                     (For mdpi devices)
values-hdpi                (For hdpi devices)
values-xhdpi               (For xhdpi devices)
values-xxhdpi              (For xxhdpi devices)
```

2. **Tablets:** Create different layout folder which is mention below:

```
layout-sw600dp             (For 7″ to 9″ Screen)
layout-sw720dp             (For 10″ to above screen)
```

**For image resources:** Create 4 drawable folders:

```
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```

Comment: is there no other way?

Answer (score 0):

Create different layouts for different screen.

res/layout-large/

res/layout-sw600dp/

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

Find android UI design examples and tutorials: http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/android-user-interface-ui-design-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Generalized densities.

```
A set of six generalized densities:
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

Just Define folder for different image like:

```
drawable-large-xhdpi: copy (drawable-xxhdpi images)
drawable-xlarge-xhdpi: copy (drawable-xxxhdpi images)
drawable-xxhdpi: 1080x1920 slicing
drawable-xxxhdpi : 1440x25601 slicing
```

Add support multiple screen size support in manifest.

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

[image: This works for me to support all tablets including Nexus 9,10, and all devices with different resolution and dencity]

Comment: xlarge, large and all that is now deprecated. User `swNNNdp`.

Comment: if we define sw600dp and sw720dp then we have to define a different layout for Nexus 9 and Nexus 10 both, That's why large and X-Large is a trick to support both with single layout.