# Android Multiple Device and screen support

Tags: android, android-layout

Im Designing a application that works both in android phone as well as tablet.
This application contains lot of images and i have created 3 different types of images
viz: mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi and placed in corresponding folder .

And created 2 layout folder one is for mobile {layout}`layout` and another for tablet and the folder name is `layout-sw600dp`.

After doing all this if run in any mobile the images look so good. but if the run in the tablet the images looks so small(its taking from mdpi folder coz the tablet is MDPI one) . how to fix with normal images and what is the procedure to go up.

Comment: You need put images in XXhdpi folder, and you need to take another layout folder for tablets like layout-720dp etc..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android UI Design: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345115/android-ui-design-supporting-multiple-screens)

Comment: no its not a duplicate

Comment: Which table are you using? It might be possible that your device resolution is between 120-160dpi. Since images are picked from there respected folder on the basis of device screen resolution. You can check it your self from this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

For designing android layout do not give fix dp  size to values, Instead of use Fill_parent, Wrap _content. Images should be put in various drawalbe folder for there defined size.

Comment: Please read the question fully. I have placed all the images in corresponding folder. i have used only wrap_content only.

Comment: If u want exact layout for particular device then you have to create that layout for that particular layout size only.

Answer (score 0):

please go through the study of dimens.xml, it plays an important part while creating screen for mobile and tablets , and also for creating design for the folders like large mdpi,xxhdpi and tvdpi.

Comment: i have created two different xml for single screen one is for mobile and another is for tablet. My question is where i need to place the images in the drawable folder for tablet design.

Comment: yes put all the images in drawable-xlarge-mdpi, and your layout-xlarge will take image from this.

Answer (score 0):

// For the 10-inch Tablets

> res/drawable-xlarge-mdpi/

// For 7-inch Tablets

> res/drawable-large-mdpi/
>
> res/drawable-large-hdpi

// For Phones

> drawable-ldpi
>
> drawable-mdpi
>
> drawable-hdpi

Please check below links.

From the [Official Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview)

[Link 1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

Hope so this will resolve your problem. Enjoy!!

Comment: Thanks first for your time. I have small doubt on this see im using 56 *56 in drawable MDPI and and what is the image size that i hv to use in the  res/drawable-large-mdpi/. thanks again

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources