# Nested CardView registration form. How to dynamically size form?

Tags: android, android-layout

[Here is a picture of my current layout](http://i.imgur.com/HQzznee.png?1)

I have been asked to create a form with a big square button at the bottom of the page.

At this point I need your help to teach me a lesson about layouts and to help me make this a dynamically sized form. I want the FIELD cards and their text to dynamically size and fill the screen with the big blue bar at the very bottom. Can I do this without orientation qualifiers and stuff?

The design I am trying to meet simply extends the zip code down depending on screensize and stops at the blue bar. While I will settle for anchoring the button and using the zip code field as  dynamic filler, I would Ideally like to have a fully dynamic form. Thanks for help! p.s. There is currently a scrollview which I would like to somehow use so that small screens can scroll through the fields down to the button.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar30"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/submit_button"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#888888"
            >

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>





        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"


            >
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/reg_email_hint"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"

                >
            </EditText>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            >


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/reg_firstName_hint"
                android:background="@null"

                android:layout_margin="20dp">
            </EditText>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            >


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/reg_lastName_hint"
                android:background="@null"

                android:layout_margin="20dp">
            </EditText>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            >


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/reg_password_hint"
                android:background="@null"

                android:layout_margin="20dp">
            </EditText>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/reg_confirmPassword_hint"
                android:background="@null"

                android:layout_margin="20dp">
            </EditText>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:hint="@string/reg_zipCode_hint"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                >
            </EditText>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#21C064"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Save" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/submit_button"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Form Field"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Trick here is give scrollview
    android:fillViewport="true"
so that the scrollview child get full height as scrollView even if the content is small
Add an empty view between last form element and Submit button like this

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

So that it will fill all maximum available space

Comment: Thanks for your help Rajesh. Now I know a little more about layouts. One more question for you: The form looks PERFECT on my 4'' device, but the space-filler View you gave me is very big on my 7'' tablet. Is there any way to dynamically size the button or the TextView font so that they are bigger on the tablet? Maybe this would be the time for an orientation qualifier?

Comment: Don't hardcode the font sizes and paddings in the layouts, instead put those values inside dimens.xml and refer it in the layout. You can override the values for tablets and phones that way. For 10'' tablet create dimens.xml in values-sw700 and give higher values.

Comment: Thought so. Still new to the IDE and how the android package works. Is it simply the folder names that gives the code the option to choose different dimens.xml's or is it some lines in Java/XML?

Comment: move your cursor to any size value like textSize or padding and do alt+enter it'll suggest you to extract resource, click ok android studio will do it for you. Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17345523/1547530

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80487/discussion-between-rajesh-batth-and-user2355058).