# Screen sizes and best background fit

Tags: android

What would be the best size or scale of width and height so I would only have to create 1 backround for a game to fit a screen or would I have to create the different densities to achieve the same affect to other screens?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android UI Design: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345115/android-ui-design-supporting-multiple-screens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do with single image you have to take a high density image so that it will support for all the screens in your **XML** file you need to mention **width** and **hight** as **"matchparent"**

the images sizes as follows

```
hdpi:

    480 x 800
    480 x 852
    540 x 960
    1024 x 600 (old 7" tablet)
    1280 x 800 (7" tablet)
    xhdpi:

    720 x 1280 (not sure, I don't have this kind of device)
    1080 x 1920
    1920 x 1080 (10" tablet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Android runs on a variety of devices that offer different screen sizes and densities. For applications, the Android system provides a consistent development environment across devices and handles most of the work to adjust each application's user interface to the screen on which it is displayed. At the same time, the system provides APIs that allow you to control your application's UI for specific screen sizes and densities, in order to optimize your UI design for different screen configurations. For example, you might want a UI for tablets that's different from the UI for handsets.

Although the system performs scaling and resizing to make your application work on different screens, you should make the effort to optimize your application for different screen sizes and densities. In doing so, you maximize the user experience for all devices and your users believe that your application was actually designed for their devices—rather than simply stretched to fit the screen on their devices.

A set of six generalized densities:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

[image]

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

> Reference :- [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)